# How to store scrapyd items in json format

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to store `scrapyd` items in a `JSON file`. Actually by default it store items in a json file but like this:
File_1:

```
{item1}
{item2}
....
```

And if i run my spider by scrapy crawl spidername -o fileName -t json

it will store item like this:
File_2:

```
[{item1},
{item2},
....]
```

If i try to copy paste contents of File_1 into [jsonParser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) i got error saying expected `[`
but File_2 works fine. Can anyone tell me how to store items in proper JSON format using scrapyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save the items directly into the database rather then storing them on the file....then storing the items from file to database... or try to read line by line from that JSON file and then do what ever you want instead of reading the whole file at a time...

Answer (score 0):

Actually its a j`son lines` format , `json` is not good for very bid data. thats why scrapy separate each `item` in a comma separated format. you can add `[ & ]` in the start and end of file it will be `json` then,

Comment: ahhh i forgot that my mistake  you needs to add comma on each line end ..

or you can read each line as dictionary as well

Answer (score -1):

Add to your `settings.py`:

```
FEED_FORMAT='json'
```

Comment: This does change the actual output to specified feed, but doesn't change the feed_uri